# Show country name on app

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic3

Im getting cordova notification on the console when I try to see my current country name on the browser.
There's something method or alternative to show me that on my tests.html, like in an input field (in the browser)?
On the other hand, if exist another alternative to show actual country name, please tell me.

tests.ts

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef } from "@angular/core";
import { NavController, IonicPage, NavParams } from "ionic-angular";
import {
  NativeGeocoder,
  NativeGeocoderReverseResult
} from "@ionic-native/native-geocoder";
import { Geolocation } from "@ionic-native/geolocation";

declare var google;

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: "page-tests",
  templateUrl: "tests.html"
})
export class TestsPage {
  @ViewChild("mapSmall") mapElement: ElementRef;

  map: any;
  message: any;
  location: any;
  gmLocation: { lat: number; lng: number } = { lat: 0, lng: 0 };

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private geolocation: Geolocation,
    private nativeGeocoder: NativeGeocoder,
    public navParams: NavParams,
  ) {
    this.onLocateUser();
  }

  onLocateUser() {
    this.geolocation
      .getCurrentPosition()
      .then(location => {
        console.log(
          "position gotten: long:",
          location.coords.longitude,
          " lat:",
          location.coords.latitude
        );
        this.location = location;
        this.gmLocation.lat = location.coords.latitude;
        this.gmLocation.lng = location.coords.longitude;
        this.nativeGeocoder.reverseGeocode(location.coords.latitude,location.coords.longitude)
  .then((result: NativeGeocoderReverseResult) => console.log(JSON.stringify(result.countryName)))
  .catch((error: any) => console.log(error));
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log("Error getting location", error);
      });
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    let latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
      this.gmLocation.lat,
      this.gmLocation.lat
    );
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.loadMap(latlng);
      this.addMarker(this.gmLocation.lat, this.gmLocation.lng);
    }, 100);
  }

  ...

}
```

Comment: Have you tried on the device?

Comment: Native will only work on device or add plaform browser.

Comment: @ImdadAli, how can i do that?

Comment: `ionic cordova run android` make sure device is connected to computer, to ensure that type `adb devices` from cmd